# Variable does not live long enough to send over channel

Tags: rust, lifetime, copy-on-write

I am trying to send a message containing `Cow<[u8]>` over a channel. However, the lifetime rules do not allow me to pass it over.

```
use std::borrow::Cow;
use std::sync::mpsc;

#[derive(Debug, Default, PartialEq, Clone)]
pub struct PlayerAction<'a> {
    pub data: Cow<'a, [u8]>,
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub enum NetworkMessage<'a> {
    PlayerActionMessage(PlayerAction<'a>),
}

pub struct ConnectionsManager<'a> {
    channel: mpsc::Sender<NetworkMessage<'a>>,
}

pub struct MessageHandler<'a> {
    pub connection_manager: ConnectionsManager<'a>,
}

fn read_message<'a>(bytes: &'a Vec<u8>) -> NetworkMessage {
    NetworkMessage::PlayerActionMessage(PlayerAction {
        data: Cow::Borrowed(&bytes),
    })
}

impl<'a> MessageHandler<'a> {
    fn on_message(&mut self, msg: Vec<u8>) {
        let readm = read_message(&msg);
        self.connection_manager.channel.send(readm);
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=248727d4e9149e3938164849e07bd938&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)

```
error[E0597]: `msg` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:30:35
   |
30 |         let readm = read_message(&msg);
   |                                   ^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
31 |         self.connection_manager.channel.send(readm);
32 |     }
   |     - borrowed value only lives until here
   |
note: borrowed value must be valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the impl at 28:1...
  --> src/main.rs:28:1
   |
28 | impl<'a> MessageHandler<'a> {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

`MessageHandler` outlives `Vec<u8>`, but I have no idea how to pass it any other way.

Is there any way to pass `Vec<u8>` so that it can live longer than the `on_message` function?

Comment: See also [Why is it discouraged to accept a reference to a String (&String), Vec (&Vec) or Box (&Box) as a function argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40006219/155423)

Comment: How do you expect this code to work? `msg` is destroyed at the end of `on_message`, but a reference to it could still be waiting in the channel. You'd then have a reference to invalid memory. **Rust prevented you from introducing memory unsafety**, that's the point of Rust.

Comment: on_message method is from TCP handler trait. I have to work with Vec<u8>. But i also need Cow<[u8]> because it is generated serialization code.

Comment: Why are you using a reference to the `msg` instead of putting the owned value in the `Cow`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a one-line change you can make to make this code correct:

```
fn on_message(&mut self, msg: &'a [u8])
```

Instead of taking a `Vec<u8>` by value, take a reference to a slice that is already guaranteed to live at least as long as `'a`. This makes it the *caller's* responsibility to ensure that whatever you pass to `on_message` will live long enough to be sent over the channel.

---

But maybe you can't do that. Either the caller will have the same problem, and you can't push it up any farther, or the `Vec<u8>` is a required part of `on_message`'s signature. If that's the case, you will have to change `read_message`. Here's one possibility:

```
fn read_message<'b>(bytes: Vec<u8>) -> NetworkMessage<'b> {
    NetworkMessage::PlayerActionMessage(PlayerAction {
        data: Cow::Owned(bytes),
    })
}

impl<'a> MessageHandler<'a> {
    fn on_message(&mut self, msg: Vec<u8>) {
        let readm = read_message(msg);
        self.connection_manager.channel.send(readm);
    }
}
```

Moving `msg` into `read_message` leaves the compiler free to pick any lifetime it wants for `'b`. In `on_message` it can just pick `'a` to make the code compile. The disadvantage of this approach is that you may have to `.clone()` the `Vec` if you need to use it again after sending it down the channel.

Comment: I think your `read_message` should be `-> NetworkMessage<'static>` for clarity.

Comment: @Shepmaster I'm thinking about it. In this case, `'static` would indeed be equivalent. But if `NetworkMessage<'b>` were invariant in `'b`, returning `NetworkMessage<'static>` would be more limiting.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I will modify the serialization lib to my needs. Quick question, is there any way to bypass borrow checkier using unsafe blocks?

Comment: @mikbal Sometimes, kind of? Instead of references, you can use raw pointers, which do not have lifetimes. But you still have to solve the *problem* of lifetimes, which is the same as in C or C++ without the handrails provided by the borrow checker.  For example, [*don't do this*](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=b31ade589371e7162771cdeb0911d2d3&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015), because it compiles, but has undefined behavior, as Shepmaster pointed out in the question comments. To use `unsafe` correctly, you must be smarter than the compiler.

Comment: @trentcl So i can't call memcpy on &msg and pass the copy to channel?

Comment: @mikbal You can use `memcpy` (or its Rust equivalent [`ptr::copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ptr/fn.copy.html)), but that doesn't solve the problem. `memcpy` doesn't allocate, so you're going to have to get that destination buffer from somewhere. Is it local? It will be invalid as soon as `on_message` returns. Do you allocate it on the heap? That's essentially the same as cloning the `Vec`, so you may as well do it the (in Rust) normal, safe way.

Comment: You can also safely write `read_message` so that it does the copy internally: [I would use `to_vec`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=a4ad22e5c213ab6bccb0c47e2e8d8733&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015). Notice that `bytes` no longer has a `'a` in its type; that's how you tell the compiler that the output lifetime is meant to be independent of `bytes`. (And yes, that can also be written as `fn read_message(bytes: &[u8]) -> NetworkMessage<'static>`.)